# K-mean clustering Data

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

In K-mean clustering problem, in order to choose the value of "K", we use several methods such as elbow method. According to Elbow method, we need to plot a graph for squared-error vs number of clusters(K) and choose the value of "K" where we find clear elbow cut. But as we go beyond the elbow cut, we get higher "K" value and lower squared-error. Then why we should not choose the larger value of "K" as it has lower squared-error?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of K-means and the elbow algorithm, you can make the error as low as you want by increasing K continuously, until the error reaches $0$ when $K = N$ (the number of data points in your data set). But that doesn't make sense, since the whole point of K-means (or any other clustering algorithm) is to group the data into groups to measure their similarity: A grouping where each data point is in its own cluster doesn't tell us anything at all about the data.

Hence the elbow method, which tries to find when there is a "sudden" change in the level of variation in the error as K increases. The idea is that while there is a rapid decrease in the error from one value of K to the next, then significant additional information is gained by increasing K. But when the error starts to decrease slowly, then the level of information gain from one K to the next is no longer significant, so you stop increasing K.

There is a problem with the elbow method however: We're not guaranteed to have a sudden change in our error curve - there is no "elbow" in the data, so how can you use the elbow method?

There are several approaches to avoid this problem:

- One way is to use a different clustering algorithm that doesn't require a fixed number of clusters (such as DBSCAN or Affinity Propagation).
- Another way is to use X-means: This is a variation K-means, where instead of minimizing the error, you try to minimize the BIC (Bayesian Information Criterion): The BIC includes an error term, but it also includes a term which penalizes the number of parameters in the model. A lower error will lower the BIC, but a higher K will increase the BIC. So when trying to minimize the BIC, you end up striking a balance between lowest error possible and lowest value of K possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it. But one doubt. What kind of additional information is gained?

Comment: @user195278 the information gained is "how similar" are your data points to each other: $K=1$ doesn't give us any information because all points are in one big cluster which doesn't tell us anything. On the other hand, $K=N$ also doesn't tell us anything because each data point is in its own unique cluster (which already knew anyway). The middle ground is where the data set is grouped into subsets - two points fall into the same cluster means they must be similar to each other in a certain way and different from the points which are in other clusters.